# Updating Ruby - bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm on MacOs 10.8.3 I had ruby 1.8.7 and i updated it to ruby 2.1.0. I'm on rails 3.2.8.

Since i update my ruby version when i'm trying to create a new app.
I get an error on the bundle install step.

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mehdisoudsane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mehdisoudsane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So i tried to do gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8 but i get this (could you please help me)

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1120:in `block in find_header'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1119:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:34:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mehdisoudsane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mehdisoudsane/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/sqlite3-1.3.8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to ruby upgrade, but to make. Are you sure you have command line tools for Xcode (Xcode -> Preferences -> downloads) installed on your Mac ? If not, install it and then retry installing sqlite.

Comment: When i go to Xcode -> Preference -> downloads i have IOS 5.0 simulator. are you talking about that?

Comment: Ok, so you should have command line tools in there as well. If it shows with a download option, install it. Or you can install it from command line with "xcode-select --install". Once that's installed, you should be good to go.

Comment: after installing the  command line tools on xcode this is ok. thank you

Comment: provide the **mkmf.log**

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you.